# RegEx for capturing numbers in parentheses

Tags: c#, regex

Example

```
Alarm Level 1 (D1) [Low (15.7)]
Alarm Level 2 [High (-12.7)]
```

I want to get `15.7` from `Alarm Level 1` and `-12.7` from `Alarm Level 2`.  I tried to use `\((.*?)\)` but it get both `D1` and `15.7 in Alarm Level 1`.

Comment: Do not use `\(([0-9-.])\)`,  it will also match `(---.....)`. Use `\((-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we can try to just collect the digits using a simple capturing group:

```
\(([0-9-.]+)\)
```

#### TEST

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"\(([0-9\-\.]+)\)";
        string input = @"Alarm Level 1 (D1) [Low (15.7)]
Alarm Level 2 [High (-12.7)]";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

```js
const regex = /\(([0-9-.]+)\)/gm;
const str = `Alarm Level 1 (D1) [Low (15.7)]
Alarm Level 2 [High (-12.7)]`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/9jS5sr/1/)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: This seems to not working on C#
Regex ip = new Regex(@"\b\(([0-9-.]+)\)\b"); did I miss something?

Comment: Note that this answer would match a number `(3)` in any context, with or without square brackets.  But, maybe this doesn't matter to the OP.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest to way to handle this would probably be to match on the following pattern:

```
\[[^(]+\((-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\)\]
```

The strategy here is to match an entire term such as `[High (-12.7)]`, and then capture the number inside round parentheses.

For example, in Python we can try the following:

```
input = """Alarm Level 1 (D1) [Low (15.7)]
           Alarm Level 2 [High (-12.7)]"""

matches = re.findall(r'\[[^(]+\((-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\)\]', input)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['15.7', '-12.7']
```

Comment: @Krsnik195: This the right answer, the other matches `...---...` or `1.2.3-4-5.6`

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expression with pattern of:

```
\[\w+\s\\([\d.-]+\\)\]
```

To match either "[Low (15.7)]" or "[High (-12.7)]" by matching

a. *"[" & "]"*    to match square bracket

b. *"\w+"*          to match one or more words ("Low" or "High" in this case)

c. *"\s"*           to match a single whitespace

d. *"\(" & "\)"*    to match parenthesis

e. *[\d.-]+*         to match combination of digits, "." & "-"

Followed by pattern of:

```
[\d.-]+
```

To capture the value required

Source Code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input = "Alarm Level 1 (D1) [Low (-15.7)]";
        string pattern = @"\[\w+\s\([\d.-]+\)\]";
        string outputA = Regex.Match(input, pattern).Value;
        string outputB = Regex.Match(outputA, @"[\d.-]+").Value;

        Console.WriteLine("A: " + outputA);
        Console.WriteLine("B: " + outputB);

        Double intOutput = Convert.ToDouble(outputB);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```